# How to Deserialize dataset to list of classes using ASP.NET Core C#

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

How to serialise dataset to object in C#? My stored procedure returns a dataset with tables based on these select statements:

```
select 
    st.Active, st.CountryCode, st.StateCode, st.StateName,st.GSTCode  
from 
    StateMaster st

select 
    ct.CountryCode, ct.CountryName, ct.Active 
from 
    CountryMaster ct

select 
    cm.Active, cm.CityCode, cm.CityName, cm.CountryCode,
    cm.CreateDate, cm.ID, cm.StateCode, cm.CreatedBy 
from 
    CityMaster cm
```

It returns:

```
{
    "Table": [
        {
            "CountryCode": "91",
            "StateCode": "01",
            "StateName": "Andhra Pradesh",
            "Active": true,
            "GSTCode": "37"
        },
        {
            "CountryCode": "91",
            "StateCode": "02",
            "StateName": "Arunachal Pradesh",
            "Active": true,
            "GSTCode": "12"
        }
    ],
    "Table1": [
        {
            "CountryCode": "91",
            "CountryName": "India",
            "Active": true
        }
    ],
    "Table2": [
        {
            "ID": 1113,
            "CityCode": "1",
            "CityName": " Alipur ",
            "StateCode": "31",
            "CountryCode": 91,
            "Active": true,
            "CreateDate": "2018-07-25T10:59:32.44",
            "CreatedBy": "6000013"
        },
        {
            "ID": 1122,
            "CityCode": "10",
            "CityName": " Bindraban ",
            "StateCode": "31",
            "CountryCode": 91,
            "Active": true,
            "CreateDate": "2018-07-25T10:59:42.437",
            "CreatedBy": "6000013"
        },
        {
            "ID": 1212,
            "CityCode": "100",
            "CityName": " Bapatla ",
            "StateCode": "01",
            "CountryCode": 91,
            "Active": true,
            "CreateDate": "2018-07-25T11:01:21.817",
            "CreatedBy": "6000013"
        }
    ]
}
```

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllClsList>(jsondpl);` returns an empty class.

Please guide me - how can I deserialize or convert dataset directly to an `AllClsList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Table`, `Table1` and `Table2` `DTO` classes for mapping data as follows:

```
public class Table
{
   public string CountryCode {get; set;}
   public string StateCode {get; set;}
   public string StateName {get; set;}
   public bool Active {get; set;}
   public string GSTCode {get; set;}
}

public class Table1
{
   public string CountryCode {get; set;}
   public string CountryName {get; set;
   public bool Active {get; set;}
}

public class Table2
{
   public string ID {get; set;}
   public string CityCode {get; set;}
   public string CityName {get; set;}
   public string StateCode {get; set;}
   public string ContryCode {get; set;}
   public bool Active {get; set;}
   public string CreateDate {get; set;}
   public string CreatedBy {get; set;}
}
```

Now write a model class containing all tables as follows:

```
public class AllTables
{
   public List<Table> Tables {get; set;}
   public List<Table1> Table1s {get; set;}
   public List<Table2> Table2s {get; set;}
}
```

Now If you received the JsonData through API call then deserialize as follows:

```
var allTables = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllTables>(yourJsonData);
```

If the stored procedure that returning the data is in your own application database then do as follows:

Your `DbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {
    }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbQuery<AllTables> AllTables { get; set; }
}
```

Then make the query as follows:

```
var allTables = context.AllTables
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.YourStoredProcedure")
    .ToList();
```

For more details: [Query Types in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types)

Comment: If you want to generate C# classes out from the json returned in Visual Studio, you can also copy all Json then click `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes`

Comment: @jwweiler Thank you! I shall try.

Comment: it might not mimick the exact functionality you wrote, but is very helpful to quickly just see what VS thinks of the JSON :)